# unable to access unix shell output from java process builder

Tags: java, unix, processbuilder

I am trying to access UNIX shell from java but output is different and I'm not sure why.

```
public class Test {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
            
        List<String> arg = new ArrayList<>();
        
        arg.add("echo");
        arg.add("$PATH");

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(arg);
        Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader br;

        if (p.waitFor() == 0) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));         
        }
        
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs :

> $PATH

I then tried to read `~/.bashrc` file to read the PATH from there.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        
        List<String> arg = new ArrayList<>();
        
        arg.add("cat");
        arg.add("<");
        arg.add("~/.bashrc");

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(arg);
        Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader br;

        if (p.waitFor() == 0) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));         
        }

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Outputs :

> cat: '<': No such file or directory
>
> cat: '~/.bashrc': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

When you execute:

```
cat < ~/.bashrc
```

your shell interprets the command, and executes `cat` with no arguments, feeding its *stdin* with the content of `~/.bashrc`.

Here, you directly call `cat` with 2 arguments, `<` and `~/.bashrc` (which by the way is not a valid filename, `~` need to be interpreted).

Therefore, unless you want to manually feed the process *stdin* by the content of `~/.bashrc`, you can just start a *shell*, by replacing:

```
arg.add("cat");
arg.add("<");
arg.add("~/.bashrc");
```

by:

```
arg.add("bash");
arg.add("-c");
arg.add("cat < ~/.bashrc");
```

Or even simpler:

```
Collections.addAll(arg, "bash", "-c", "cat < ~/.bashrc");
```

Or even even simpler:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "cat < ~/.bashrc");
```

Comment: ok then one more question. why output for `"echo", "$PATH"` is $PATH ??

Comment: For the very same reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the PATH details you can use

`System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));`